# Does CouchDB have any default indexes?

Tags: database, couchdb

I just had a quick question that I feel the StackOverflow community might be able to answer.

I looked at the documentation for CouchDB but to no avail. I was interested in knowing if CouchDB created any indexes by default?

Hopefully, the question is clear as it is for an assignment and I picked the CouchDB database to study more.

Comment: Yes, the [_all_docs](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/bulk-api.html#get--db-_all_docs) endpoint may be considered the primary (loosely, default) index. Here's a [good write up](https://pouchdb.com/2014/05/01/secondary-indexes-have-landed-in-pouchdb.html) about using (and abusing) `_id`; although it's regarding pouchDB, it comports to CouchDB.

Comment: So the primary key can be considered to be the default index right?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you meant by "_all_docs endpoint may be considered the primary (loosely, default) index"

Comment: For any given database the value of `_id` for all documents are indexed.  That index is accessed from the `_all_docs` endpoint.  The comment section is not a good place to explain beyond what I've done.  Read up on `_all_docs` and [views](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/ddoc/views.html#db-design-design-doc-view-view-name).